# Python: Iterating over predetermined conditions within conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, conditional-statements

I need to iterate over a number of attributes inside an object. Each attribute is initialized as None and over the course of the program each will store a separate object. There are 16 attributes that I need to iterate over and the condition is that the attributes will store objects in a predetermined sequence. For example, if attribute 10 is empty, then attributes 11 to 16 will also be empty, therefore I will not need to iterate past any empty attributes. My initial result was to use 'if' statements for each attribute like this:

```
Class Object1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute1=None
        self.attribute2=None
        self.attribute3=None
        self.attribute4=None
        ...

    def repeating_function(self):
        if self.attribute1!=None:
            self.attribute1.attribute=Callback1
        if self.attribute2!=None:
            self.attribute2.attribute=Callback2
        if self.attribute3!=None:
            self.attribute3.attribute=Callback3
        ...
```

But, because of the sequence in which the attributes store objects, I ended up with this:

```
class Object1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute1=None
        self.attribute2=None
        self.attribute3=None
        self.attribute4=None
        self.attribute5=None

    def repeating_function(self):
        if self.attribute1!=None:
            self.attribute1.attribute=Callback1
            if self.attribute2!=None:
                self.attribute2.attribute=Callback2
                if self.attribute3!=None:
                    self.attribute3.attribute=Callback3
                    ...
```

Basically, my question is: if the second example is more efficient at iterating over the non-empty attributes. Because I'm adding conditions inside conditions in the second example, I'm not sure which method is more efficient.

Comment: If by "efficient" you mean speed, forget it. Think about how long it's going to take you to write, read or maintain such code. Figure out a way to do it with a list or dictionary, and forget the microseconds.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you want a `list`, `dict` or even a separate class instead of 16 single attributes. The code would be horrible instead.

Comment: Btw.: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a list instead of separate attributes:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.attributes = []
```

With this,

- to add an attribute, use `self.attributes.append(...)`;
- to find out how many (non-`None`) attributes there are, use `len(self.attributes)`;
- to refer to the final non-`None` attribute, use `self.attributes[-1]`;

and so on.